# filtering a collection in jQuery expression

Tags: jquery

I am reading about filtering values in jQuery, and I passed on this example:

```
myvalues = $("div.myvalues");
myvalues.filter(function(index){
    return !!$(this).val().length;
});
```

I am wondering what does the `!!$(this).val().length;` mean? I know that ! is flipping the operator to false, and !! is flipping it again to true, but what's the idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this `return !!$(this).val().length;` will filter out or give every element that doest have `value` attribute set. of course which means value length will be `zero` a `false` when checked with `!!`

Comment: So the filter method will use the returned true/false by the !! to apply the filters aha. :D thanks.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford yeah , my pleasure :) where there will be true it keep those and where false it will remove